# Are fibers available in iOS (aka user mode threads, cooperative multitasking)?

Tags: ios, multithreading

Are fibers available in iOS (aka user mode threads, cooperative multitasking)?

I'm not too interested in a debate as to whether or not they're a good idea (IMO user mode threads are often a good alternative to state machines, or nodejs-like callback models). I'm just trying to figure out if this is something I will have available in my toolbox.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29

(Clarifying the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Both the `pthreads` library and Foundation's `NSThread` object provide this functionality.

(In general, the restrictions in iOS don't affect POSIX-compliance - all functions in the POSIX C standard library are available, libpthreads is no exception.)

Edit: [setcontext function family](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/setcontext.html).

Comment: Sorry I think my question was unclear. I'm interested in fibers (some folks call these user mode threads).